Why AWS Lambda is not sending emails using Oauth2 and Microsoft graph API?
I am hosting my API (.Net core 6) on AWS Lambda, and I deployed the code which does the OAuth2 authentication after sending request through endpoint and uses graph API to send emails. The email is configured using a client ID, client secret and tenant ID. The code works fine in the local machine but can't get the token when running in Lambda. Can you help me on it?
Lambda cannot process this line of code. (No errors found in logs; it just stops there):
var result = await _confidentialClientApplication
        .AcquireTokenForClient(OAuth2.scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

My Scope:
public static readonly string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

Code which is initiating above code:
await graphClient.Users[_mailSettings.userId].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);

Note, even if i hardcode the token value, it still does not send emails.

Does it throw any exception? Could the recipient check junks folder? What permissions have been granted to the app?

Can you please share little more code? How are you creating _confidentialClientApplication object?

Thank you for your response. But as per the Microsoft copilot answer, i removed await and added separate line as result.wait(). Same for send email. It worked with lamba. The issue is resolved.
